# Comparison in Multi-party Computation without bit decomposition

Tags: multiparty-computation

There are MPC comparison protocols which can securely compute $(a<^?0):=\begin{cases}1,\text{ if }a<0\\ 0,\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$, where $a$ is an element of a prime-order field (of course one needs a notion of what $"<"$ even means in this case). But to my knowledge, all of them use some kind of bit decomposition protocol which outputs shared bits $[a_0],[a_1],\ldots,[a_k]$ on input $\textstyle \left[\sum^k_{i=0}a_i2^i\right]$. Does anyone know of such a comparison protocol which does not require bit decomposition?

Comment: Are you interested only in the setting of more than two parties, or are you also looking for solutions in the 2-party setting?

Comment: I'm curious about both.

Answer (score 1):

In the two-party setting, there are fast protocols for securely comparing two shared integers that do not go through bit decomposition. For example:

**If you want to optimize online communication** (but are ok with paying more communication in an input-independent preprocessing phase), then the best approaches rely on function secret sharing, see [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/1095) and the improvements in [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1392).

**If you want low end-to-end communication**, then I think [this protocol](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/544.pdf) used to be state-of-the-art (disclaimer: I'm the author, and this area evolves, there might be better protocols out there). After a quick Google search, my best bet is that there might be faster protocols (less rounds and communication) in this [more recent paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3372297.3417274?casa_token=jY_533ihCoEAAAAA:uzo2SCrvJ6CWOjlMVjAiJlatkEIJriuD1NOk8Xe3R2WOpS4eYETGWvw9hzZkVOqWV3RUHVwKfn8), but I did not read it in full details (I still checked that they don't go through shared bit decomposition).

Answer (score 0):

Bit decomposition is sufficient, but not necessary, for comparison. In general, the comparison $a<b$ is equivalent to $0<b-a$, which corresponds to extracting the most significant bit of $x=b-a$. There are many ways of extracting such bit without extracting all of them. See for example:

- ["Rabbit: Efficient Comparison for Secure Multi-Party Computation"](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/119.pdf)
- ["ACCO: Algebraic Computation with Comparison"](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3474123.3486757)
- ["Improved Primitives for MPC over Mixed Arithmetic-Binary Circuits"](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/338.pdf)

Comment: Does this work because the MSB encodes the sign of $b-a$?

Comment: Yes, correct. The MSB (in two-complement representation) is $1$ if $b-a$ is negative, and $0$ otherwise.